# Safety of using negative em values for letter-spacing

Tags: css, font-size

Is it safe to use negative em values for letter-spacing? For example I want to use `letter-spacing: -0.028em;` I tried it on Chrome, Opera, Firefox (latest versions) and it work great. But will it work on older versions too?

Comment: About `rem`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem.

Comment: You can test this yourself, but we can't answer because we don't know which "older" browsers you want to check on. Test it on all the browser versions you want to support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`em` is just a standard or a unit for calculating the value to be used for the object rendering.

**It is safe** and you can use it with positive as well as negative values, em has been in for a long time so most of the old browser would be good to it.

Answer (score 1):

The W3 states that negative values, for the length, of `letter-spacing` are permitted, so yes; they should be functional. This depends on the browsers themselves, however, and their fidelity to, and implementation of, the specification.

Reference:

- [`letter-spacing`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/letter-spacing).
- [Letter and word spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-letter-spacing).